# TypeScript: how to get anonymous type passed into angle bracket?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<
  {propItem1: string},
  {stateItem1: string}
> {
  constructor(props: ???) { // how to reference the prop type?
  }
  render() {
  }
}
```

I know one solution is to refactor the prop's type as a named interface, but can it be done this way as well (without repeating the type definition)?

Comment: Then you have to decide if you think those *"style reasons"* outweigh the repetition.

Comment: Is repetition the only alternative way?

Comment: It's really not clear why you don't just do the obvious thing.

Comment: I am simply trying to understand nuances about the language. Why the negativity? It's merely a question about how the language works.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the same type. If the same type is described twice, they will be considered compatible.

Obviously naming the type is more elegant in this case, but you know that.